# Google Analytics clientside scope and workflow?

Tags: google-analytics

I have some questions about setting up GA ecommerce and use of analytics.js functions.

The flow of purchase is:

1.) Product Page > payapl.com > member's area

Will this work?

Product Page:

```
<script>
ga('require', 'ecommerce');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name.
  'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total.
  'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping.
  'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax.
});
</script>
```

Member's Area after redirect from PayPal:

```
<script>
ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
```

My concern is: Will it know this is the same user/session after the interruption with paypal?  Will all of the transaction info still be there (in a cookie?) to send?

You can see I'm doing everything client side, which I'd rather do if possible.

Some additional info on my setup:

I don't have access to any cart items on the thank you page.  It is a buy now and no carts are used.  Each of my products has its own thank you page so I always know what was purchased when the user lands on that specific thank you page.  They are coming from Stripe or PayPal once they land on the thank you page.  The part I won't have is how much they paid since I do run discounts via coupons.

Reference for GA analytics.js: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

Answer (score 1):

It would not.

GA ecommerce:addTransaction is creating sort of data container, which stores info about all items finally purchased, ready to be send. This container has local (single page) range. Ecommerce:send must be called on the same page as addTransaction did, otherwise it will send you empty cart.

If on the "Thank you!" page you have no access to the cart data, you should store them inside session cookie still on the Product Page and create a GA virtual cart using addTransaction with all items at once along with sending them.

Comment: I've added some additional info in the OP.  In my case, you are saying I should do all GA ecommerce on the thank you page?  How can I handle discounts (see updated OP)?

Comment: I think you have 3 options. First - add discount info to the session cookie on product page and read it on Thank you page to modify price. Second - pass this info in return url parameter of paypal. I'm not an expert about paypal but after reading [this](https://www.paypal.com/ie/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pop/express_return_url-outside) I suppose it is possible. Third - use enchanced ecommerce in GA. In enchanced ecommerce you are able to add info about coupon/discount as on option of checkout step and send it if user will click Paypal redirect button. Or send discount as internal promotion click.

Comment: Enchanced Ecommerce:
[checkout steps](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#checkout-steps), 
[internal promotion click](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-promo-clicks)